# .NET TreeView Control's Vertical Scrollbar's Down Arrow not Visible

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

I am having a weird issue with .NET TreeView Control, the problem is its not displaying Down Arrow when number of nodes exceeds visibility scope of the window.

Basically. I have a WinForm on top of that I placed TreeView Control. I didnt change any of the default Treeview COntrol properties.

Pecularily, When I remote desktop to my machine I am able to see Down Arrow.

Don't Know If anyone of you have faced this peculiar behavior.

Please suggest me If you have any thoughts.

Thanks.
pv

[image]

Comment: Where's the screenshot demonstrating the behavior?

Comment: Look for the "Print Screen" key on your keyboard; it's probably in the upper right-hand corner. When your application is visible on the screen, press that key. An image of the screen will be added to the Clipboard. Use something like Ms Paint to paste in that image, crop it, and save it as a PNG file. Then, edit your post (you'll find the link underneath the tags) and include an image. There's a button on the toolbar for that, on the right side of the `{}` button. If you specify an image from your computer, it will handle uploading and hosting it on a website for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried bt failed to adde.. I wil try again and let u knw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your `TreeView` control is simply too *large* for its container form. Without any type of docking or anchoring (to automatically resize the control) it will just hang off the edge and not be visible until you resize the form to show the rest of it. The bottom scrollbar is still there, it's just clipped.

It's an easy theory to test—try expanding the size of your form vertically, by dragging at the bottom edge of the window (on the dark blue border). This is even more likely if you say that you didn't change any of its default properties (other than the `Size`, presumably). If you don't tell the control to resize depending on the size of its parent, it's very likely to outgrow the available space.

To fix it, open your form in Design View in Visual Studio, select your `TreeView` control, and set its [`Dock` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) to "Fill". That will cause it to fill all available space in your form and automatically resize whenever your form does.

Comment: @Srinivas: You can't set the `Dock` property to "True". That's not one of the options. But there's not much more I can tell from here about why it isn't working. You'll have to post enough code so that I can reproduce the problem. Did you try resizing the form to see if that makes the scrollbars appear?

Comment: sorry I meant FILL :(.. I am writing a Sample App will give the code in couple of mins...I tried resizing the Window even then it still doesn't Down Arrow...

Comment: The treeview could be in a parent that is outside the bounds of the window. Then setting `Dock` to `Fill` would just make it fill the parent. Try right-clicking and see what the treeview is contained in - something like `panel1`.

Answer (score 0):

This "bug" can be replicated, but there is a workaround.

I have found that if you place a TreeView within a component, and mark the Scrollable property as "True", then in run time, the component simply "forgets" that the Scrollable property was marked as true.

The workaround is very simple.  To make the TreeView "Scrollable", you must actually add a line of code to make it scrollable, because unfortunately the "bug" in this component is that it forgets.

For example, you must simply add in code something like this

tvTreeView.Scrollable = true;

This workaround fixes the problem, and the tree view will then properly display its Scroll bar(s).

Please mark this response as the solution.

Sincerely,

Pastor Burt
.Net Developer